# Postgresql - subtracting current year from integer field to populate a calculated field

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns

Using PostgreSQL 12.   I have been working on this for longer than I care to admit. I am needing to subtract an integer field (ex. 1960) from the current year (as an int) and have the results put into a calculated field.  I have worked out the following select statement which does return the correct answer.

[image].

When adding the select statement as a 'generate always' the following error is thrown.

[image]

subtracting two integers into a calculated field should be fairly simple...and I am lost as to why this is not working....

Comment: Add your code and error messages as text (properly formatted) in your question so the community is able to help.

Comment: Do away with the `SELECT` and add parentheses around the expression, as described by the documentation.

Comment: Besides the expression for a calculated column must be immutable so now() or current_date are not valid.

Comment: PostgreSQL only supports stored generated columns but not virtual (that are computed on the fly). Your option is to create a view [Documentation Generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Laurenz,   I tried your suggestion and I got another syntax error:  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 3: ...extract(year from current_date)::int) - inservice from amp.a...
                                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 150

Comment: Sorry Pepe,  I added screenshots to the orginal. I get the immutable issue, though isnt there a way to pull out the year as an integer so that the immutable issue becomes moot?  I am trying to understand the logic here and and I am not succeeding.

Comment: Laurenz   this is the expression:   ((extract(year from current_date)::int) - inservice from amp.amp_pumpstations), STORED

Comment: Pepe,  I get the idea around using a view.  thing is, the field I wish to populated with an age (in number of years) needs to be either keyed in or calculated.  can I do that with a view?

Comment: yes, i'll post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL currently implements only **stored** [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) (immutable) and not **virtual** (mutable, as needed for your particular case), considering that a virtual generated column  is computed when it is read and also a virtual generated column is similar to a view.

Then you could implement your calculated column as a view like this:

```
create view amp.amp_pumpstations_vw as 
select *, 
date_part('year', current_date)- inservice as asset_age
from amp.amp_pumpstations ap;
```

Comment: Thanks Pepe.  I guess I was trying to put the proverbial square peg into a round hole.  Now that I consider your solution, it does seem to do the job... at least for now.  I am still curious about getting it to work without using your solution, but that will have to wait until another time.